# SFINAE when using lvalue ref but success when using rvalue ref

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++17, sfinae

I searched but really couldn't find an answer why SFINAE happens only when the argument is passed by lvalue ref, but the build succeeds when the arg is passed by rvalue ref:

```
template <typename T>
class A {
 public:
  using member_type = T;
};

template <typename AType>
typename AType::member_type f(AType&& m) {
  typename AType::member_type res{};
  return res;
}

void demo() {
  A<int> a;

  // ERROR: candidate template ignored: substitution failure 
  // [with AType = A<int> &]: type 'A<int> &' 
  // cannot be used prior to '::' because it has no members
  f(a); 

  // BUILD SUCCESS
  f(std::move(a)); 
}
```

Comment: Just read the error message. `A<int> & :: member_type` is invalid.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Thanks for the reply! What I don't understand is why `A<int> & :: member_type` is invalid, while `A<int> && :: member_type` is valid. Could you explain a little more? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think `AType = A<int>&&`? You already have `&&` in the parameter type, `AType&&`.

Comment: @evg That's a forwarding reference.

Comment: @Spencer And so what? For an rvalue, `AType` will be deduced to a non-reference type.

Comment: @Evg Which isn't obvious from your previous comment.

Comment: @Spencer It was just a hint. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have

```
template <typename AType>
typename AType::member_type f(AType&& m)
```

You have what is called a forwarding reference. Even though it looks like an rvalue reference, this reference type can bind to lvalues or rvalues.  The way it works is when you pass an lvalue to `f`, `AType` gets deduced to being `T&`, and when you pass an rvalue `AType` gets deduced to just `T`.

So, when you do `f(a);` `AType` gets deduced as `A<int>&`, and you try to form the return type of `A<int>&::member_type` which is invalid as references do not have type members.

Conversely when you do `f(std::move(a));`, `AType` gets deduced to `A<int>` and `A<int>` does have a `member_type` type member.

To fix this you can remove the reference-ness of type by using [`std::decay_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) like

```
template <typename AType>
auto f(AType&& m) {
  typename std::decay_t<AType>::member_type res{};
  return res;
}
```

Comment: @Spencer Yea, I like that better, especially since `remove_cvref` is a C++20 feature.

Comment: The only thing bad about `decay_t` is the array-to-pointer decay.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks for the detailed explanation!

"references do not have type members"

This is obvious from the compiler error message, but is there any documents on it? I searched online but didn't find any.

Comment: @llxxee Not sure if there is something in the standard but a reference is just that.  It is an alias to another object.  It isn't that object and it isn't the same type as the object it refers to.

Comment: There are 14 categories of types in the c++ type system.  See <type_traits> for details, the is_XXXXX traits categorize each type (all types only are in one such category).  lvalue and rvalue references are their own categories, which are separate from class (& struct) types.  While it may or not be explicitly stated, different types behave differently, and references are not classes and do not have nested types.